# HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL for url ending with .html file in wildfly

Tags: java, post, servlets, jboss, wildfly-11

I'm working on integrating azure ad for my application's login function. on successful authentication azure will return the access token to the redirect URL which is mentioned. problem is that I'm getting "HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL" while redirecting.

This is how the redirecting URL look like.

https://bbb-dev-ext.abcde.com/myapp.dashboard/azureLogin.html?

the web server that we use for my app is wildfly 11

tried adding the below in my web.xml still it didn't worked

```
<security-constraint>    
  <display-name>Example Security Constraint</display-name>    
  <web-resource-collection>    
     <web-resource-name>Protected Area</web-resource-name>    
     <url-pattern>/azureLogin.html*</url-pattern>   
     <http-method>GET</http-method>    
  </web-resource-collection>
</security-constraint>
```

Is there any other way to change my request http method type from POST to GET ? or is there any way to allow HTTP method type POST in wildfly application ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it worked after converting the html to a jsp file. looks like there is some with Jboss while handling POST request to a html page.